# After downloading file installer process runs and uses all memory

Tags: macos, safari, memory

When I download a file from the internet a process starts with name "installer" and uses all the available memory until my Mac crashes.

It's not related to the browser — I tested with Chrome and Safari.
The only solution I have is to kill the process from Terminal.

What is installer? How can I delete installer process from my Mac?

I have a 15″ Retina MacBook Pro with 16 GB memory.

Comment: What is it you are trying to download? Or does it happen with all downloads.

Comment: Yes it happen for all download and it's run for each download it means that if i download two file in one time it's process run two time.

Comment: @Majid, can you found any solutions regarding installer file issue? It' s always required to kill using activity monitor.

Answer (score -1):

I used EasyFind. It located right away all the files and folders matching my research criterias (in that specific case I was looking for "installer")
Deleted it right away.
Worked like a charm!