# macOS Sierra keeps running out of application memory

Tags: macbook-pro, applications, memory, activity-monitor, memory-pressure

Every time I turn my Mac on, after a while the app memory just runs out.

[image]

[image]

These are just from 10min apart, after working for a while. I need help figuring what those Installers are and why the kernel_task is taking so much memory. Those Google Chrome Helpers also look extremely unnecessary.

The only thing that 'solves' this is restarting the computer. How can I get rid of this cycle?

Comment: The kernel_task and Google Chrome helpers are normal - they serve a purpose. You cannot run Google Chrome without the helpers. However the installers taking up so much memory is a problem. Have you checked your login items for installers? - Have you tried stopping the installer processes from activity monitor? (select the installer and then click the cross in the top left bar)

Comment: Possibly related - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/129435/after-downloading-file-installer-process-runs-and-uses-all-memory & http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/255993/os-x-el-capitan-installer-app-has-crippled-my-mac-mini

Comment: @jksoegaard oh ok, I thought they were high. That fixed the Installers problem for now, hopefully they won't come back.. Thank you!!!

Comment: Those installer processes are causing the high memory usage

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is probably launching when macOS starts, and tabs from your previous session and reopening, so you're instantly running out of memory.

Try the Chrome plugin, The Great Suspender. Also try running Dr. Cleaner continuously in the background.

Answer (score -2):

But the answer is right there. You have zillions of "Chrome Helper" processes eating up all your memory. Quick Chrome and recheck your state.

Why Chrome behaves like this?  Either:

1. you keep a zillion pages open, each with some very-heavy web app (like Google docs and such)
2. you have a "malware" installed on your Mac which leeches on Chrome, making it open lot's of extensions on your behalf. Download and run "MalwareBytes" free malware remover for Mac to see if that's the case.
3. Have you joined any of those vicious "programs" of "download this and receive 99 cents per run of our software" ??? Maybe you rolled into some bad program where you actually "sell your Mac cycles" for others? That "Chrome helper" is a background-only mac "Daemon" running within Chrome, and doing something. It would be nice to know what.

As a first step - close all your chrome windows and tabs - individually, and manually. make sure no page is open in chrome - and look again on your activity monitor. If those hogs are all gone - you're done. Quit Chrome, and you're clear.

Comment: No as tyhe comments say CVhrome etc is normal - the iissues are the installers

Comment: A very good answer.